# "require" not working in dr racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I am new to scheme and I am trying to trace a function. I have to load the "trace" function. According to the racket documentation, I have to execute a:

> (require racket/trace)

But the response I am getting back is

> require: undefined; 
>   cannot reference undefined identifier

I am baffled. I am using language "R5RS" if that makes a difference. can't find anything online or on stack overflow on this.

Comment: If you want to do most anything useful with Racket, you can't use the R5RS language. Please choose a different language, such as Racket (choose "Use the language declared in the source", then put `#lang racket` at the top of your file), if you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chris Jester-Young's comment is correct: don't use R5RS.  In the standard R5RS language, there's no such thing as a module.  Go look at http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/; not a word about a module, right?

Racket takes the standard more seriously than you'd expect: if you tell it to work in R5RS mode, it will turn **off** language features that the standard does not describe.

If you're using the Racket toolchain, don't use the R5RS language unless you really want to work in a restrictive language.  Use standard *#lang racket* instead.  See: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/intro.html which shows how to use it in that mode.

Comment: Thank you. Althought a minor note is to put the "#lang racket" in the text file with the program code, not in the interactions window.

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
(#%require racket/trace)
```